# repaint() call from the constructor

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to display loaded resource-image.
And it works, but only after user resized the window.

```
import javax.swing.*; import java.awt.*;

class MyMainWindow extends JFrame{
    Image img;

    public MyMainWindow(){
        setSize(300,300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        img = MyResourceLoader.getImage("res.jpg");
        repaint();

        setVisible(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void paint (Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        if (img != null)
            g.drawImage(img, 0,0, null);
    } 
}

public class ResourcesProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyMainWindow();
    } 
}
```

Why the constructor's repaint() call doesn't work?
And what should I do to show this image from the start?

Resource Loader class:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class MyResourceLoader{
    static MyResourceLoader rl = new MyResourceLoader();
    static public Image getImage(String fileName){
        return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(rl.getClass().getResource("images/" + fileName));
    }
}
```

Comment: `repaint` doesn't work, because the frame has not yet been realised on the screen, therefore, there is nothing to paint...

Comment: How does `MyResourceLoader.getImage(...);` actually work?

Comment: Also, change `g.drawImage(img, 0,0, null);` to `g.drawImage(img, 0,0, this);` and you might actually get a nice surprise.  Also, don't override `paint` of top level containers, there are other components on the `JFrame` which can interfere with the painting.  Instead, use a `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method and add that to the frame

Comment: Try:

setVisible(true);
pack();

Comment: g.drawImage(img, 0,0, this) seved the situation. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: *"g.drawImage(img, 0,0, this) seved the situation."*  Yes, those people who publish examples that use `null` when they have a perfectly good `ImageOberserver` should be flayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so a bunch of things...

## First...

Because the window has not yet been realised on the screen (attached to a native peer), there is nothing for `repaint` to paint...

## Second...

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(rl.getClass().getResource("images/" + fileName));
```

Passes the actually loading of the image to a background thread, meaning that while you get a non-null value returned, the actual image data might not have been fully loaded.

You should consider using `ImageIO.read` instead, it will only return AFTER the image data has been fully loaded and will also throw an exception if something goes wrong (unlike `Toolkit.getImage`).  See [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details...

## Third...

All Swing components implement the `ImageObserver` interface, this means when you call `Graphics#drawImage`, you should pass the object as the `ImageObserver` parameter

```
g.drawImage(img, 0,0, this);
```

This allows the component to monitor updates from the loading of the image and reschedule repaint as required.

## Fourth...

You should avoid overriding `paint` of top level containers, apart from not been double buffered, there is a bunch of components between the frame and the user, which can interfere with the painting process.

Instead, you should extend from something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method, performing your custom painting there.  You should then add this panel to an instance of `JFrame` (or some other component as needed)

Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

## Fifth...

You should be making sure that you create and modify your UI only from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Paint is immediately called when the code is initialized. To see this, get rid of `repaint();` in your constructor, and add in your `paint` method, `g.drawLine(0, 0, 300, 300)`;

Comment: Your image loader and drawing techniques are implemented incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you may have to add some imports:

```
import javax.swing.*; import java.awt.*;

class MyMainWindow extends JFrame{
    Image img;

    public MyMainWindow(){
        setSize(300,300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        img = MyResourceLoader.getImage("res.jpg");
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint (Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        if (img != null)
            g.drawImage(img, 0,0, this);
    } 
}

public class ResourcesProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyMainWindow();
    } 
}
```

Resource Loader:

```
import javax.swing.*; import java.awt.*;

public class MyResourceLoader {
    public static Image getImage(String fileName){
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(fileName));
        return icon.getImage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Essentially `ImageIcon` is the same as using `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage`, better to use `ImageIO.read`